# Accept either single dict or list of dicts as function argument

Tags: python

I'd like to accept either one dict or a list of dicts as a function argument. So far, I've come up with the following, but I suspect I've missed something completely obvious, and am using something fragile (`isinstance`):

```
def wrap(f):
    def enc(inp):
        if isinstance(inp, list):
            for item in inp:
                f(item)
        else:
            f(inp)
    return enc

@wrap
def prt(arg):
    # do something with the dict
    print arg.keys()
```

Comment: Don't just think in lists. A sequence of dicts could also be passed as a tuple, a set, or even a generator expression, and the same code in your function could safely iterate over any of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would accept a variable number of arguments:

```
def wrap(f):
    def enc(*args):
        for item in args:
            f(item)
    return enc
```

Then you can either pass a single dictionary, multiple dictionaries or a list by unpacking it.

See [Arbitrary Argument Lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) in the Python tutorial.

Comment: There no point accepting `kwargs` if you're going to drop them on the floor.

Comment: @Ned: True, I guess it was habit... removed.

Comment: @urschrei: Why? `enc` is looping over all arguments, so each `item` is a dictionary and is passed to `f`.

Comment: @felix-kling When I use your version of `wrap` in python 2.7 it prints the dict or the list of dicts, whichever I pass. It doesn't seem to actually be unpacking the list. See here: https://gist.github.com/1193001

Comment: @urschrei You are passing in you dictionaries as a list in your gist example. *args creates the list for you, so just `prt({foo:"foo"},{bar:"bar"})` will do the trick.

Comment: @urschrei: *You* have to unpack the list. Have a look at the link in my answer. The call should be: `prt(*[{'b': 'bar'}, {'c': 'baz'}])`. Or pass the dictionary as normal arguments, as @Mark showed.

Comment: @felix kling Argh, *that's* what I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid using a decorator, I think it would be easier to handle the logic for that in your `ptr` function:

```
def prt(arg):
    try:
        # we'll try to use the dict...
        print arg.keys()
    except AttributeError:
        # ok that didn't work, we have a list of dicts
        for d in arg:
            print d.keys()
```