# Accept either single value or list as argument

Tags: python, arguments

I want to write a function with an argument which can be either:

- a single argument
- a list of arguments

E.g. `symlink(target_or_targets, destination)`, which could be called as either:

- `symlink(target, destination)`
- `symlink([target1, target2], destination)`

How do I test for a single argument, and convert it into a list with one item?

(Note: I don't want to use a [decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299944/accept-either-single-dict-or-list-of-dicts-as-function-argument) or  [`*args`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/919680/5353461))

Answer (score 1):

### Convert to list if given a single argument

Stricter version:

```
if type(target_or_targets) not in (list, set, tuple):
    targets = [target_or_targets]
```

More permissive:

```
if not isinstance(target_or_targets, (list, set, tuple)):
    targets = [target_or_targets]
```